# Clear log files on OpenShift - RedHat

Tags: logging, openshift, redhat, paas

Debugging my apps on OpenShift is becoming difficult due to excessive log data. 
I'm using the terminal command  **rhc tail -a appname** to view logs

Is there a way to clear the log files via a **rhc** command? (or any other method)

Any other recommendations for viewing / handling log data on OpenShift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rhc app-tidy <yorApp>` to delete the logs and contents of the `/tmp` directory on the gears (this is used primarily in order to free up some disk space).

You can also ssh into your app `rhc ssh <yourApp>` and check individual logs in `~/app-root/logs/`, which may bring some clarity if you are reading only the log that interests you.

Answer (score 1):

**Configure logs**

To set

- maximum file size
- maximum number of files

> The maximum file size and maximum number of files can be configured
>   with the LOGSHIFTER__MAX_FILESIZE and
>   LOGSHIFTER__MAX_FILES environment variables.

```
$ rhc env set LOGSHIFTER_PHP_MAX_FILESIZE=5M LOGSHIFTER_PHP_MAX_FILES=5 -a myapp
Setting environment variable(s) ... done
$ rhc app stop
RESULT:
myapp stopped
$ rhc app start
RESULT:
myapp started
```

> The exact variable names depend on the type of cartridge; the value of
>    is DIY, JBOSSAS, JBOSSEAP, JBOSSEWS, JENKINS, MONGODB,
>   MYSQL, NODEJS, PERL, PHP, POSTGRESQL, PYTHON, or RUBY as appropriate.

copied from:
https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html
https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html